# Laravel, what can cause random CSRF TokenMismatch error?

Tags: php, laravel, http, laravel-5.3

Sometimes I get CSRF `TokenMismatch` error when submitting a form in my Laravel app. Not sure when exactly, but it can happen even when I opened the form page 1 minute ago.

But after returning back and F5 it works. So it looks like the form page was cached somehow and used old token?

Why this could happen?

Currently I am using `artisan serve`, maybe it can cause this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your session expires, take a look to `app/config/session.php` and check the `lifetime` parameter and the `expire_on_close` :

```
'lifetime' => 120,
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

**NOTE :** `lifetime` in minutes not seconds.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have the same default values, 120/false.